# Active record find_by where attribute in collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Sorry if this is a newbie question, searching google and SO turns up nothing, I am probably not using the right terms, but here goes ....

If I have a User model with a name, and I want to find a 'john' I know I can do

```
User.find_by_name 'john'.
```

Great.

But suppose I have a list of names that I want to retrieve. I could do a find_by for each name in the list - resulting in multiple sql queries. Or I could do User.all and filter the result in memory against my list.

Both seem like they could be quite expensive and not very scalable, when in raw sql I could just write:

```
select * from users where name in ('john', 'peter', 'susan', ... );
```

And get the whole lot in one query.

Am I missing a trick or can active record do this too? If not then what is the recommended best way to do this from within a rails 3 application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
names = ['John', 'Mary']
users = User.where(name: names)
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.find_all_by_name(names)` works too, though it's probably considered old school now.